# Camel Rest XML DSL to separate folder results Unmarshall Exception

Tags: xml, rest, apache-camel, dsl

Facts:
1] Camel Spring Boot version 2.19.0
2] Attempt for Camel XML DSL Rest

**Problem Statement :** 
As per given example I moved my Camel context to a separate folder called "camel" under main/resources folder of Spring Boot project. 
However upon invocation it throws Unmarshall Exception **CamelSpringBootInitializationException unexpected element**

I removed them and added to another folder then none of the routes got detected !!
    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

```
<camel:camelContext id="chCoolCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <restConfiguration  bindingMode="auto" component="restlet" port="9091" />

    <rest path="/chcool">
        <get uri="pipeRequestXN2">
            <to uri="direct-vm:getNewYearDiscount" />
        </get>
    </rest>

    <route id="assocDisc-RequestRoute">
        <from uri="direct-vm:getNewYearDiscount" />
        <process ref="newYearDiscReqProcessor"></process>
    </route>
</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="newYearDiscReqProcessor" class="com.wm.mad.disc.camel.processor"></bean>
```

Any help in the matter? How to add them so that it is automatically detected by Boot. I need to use XML DSL as the rest of the routes are existing applications.

Answer (score 2):

It may been a bug in that Camel 2.19.x version so XML route are not automatic loaded. Try upgrade to latest release of either 2.19.x or 2.20.x.

Comment: Thanks,  I guess so.  

But when I did applied a different way as a solution- instead of adding it application properties I did import resource in SrpingBoot Starter class and it worked perfectly fine for me. 

@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml")

Comment: Just an additional comment on my testing with spring boot 2.20.1 version which met with same error fate. (I mean going back to application.prop entries for spring context xml path) CamelSpringBootInitializationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans", local:"beans").
RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:229) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]***